# SQL Server 2005 cd Key

Tags: sql-server-2005, product-key

I need to get the cd key of my installed instance of SQL Server 2005.  I've used the following code and it doesn't work, most likely because I think it was for SQL Server 2000.  Please help.

```
USE master
USE master
EXEC xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\80\registration',
'CD_KEY'
```

Comment: Why? MS will never ask for it...

Comment: And that reg key is SQL 2000 anyway

Comment: that's what i've been told, but the cd that i have asks for it.  it's a sql server 2005 standard disc with sp1.  dunno why it asks but it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We bought a product that retrieves cd keys.

Answer (score 1):

Use ProduKey.It'll find all the serial key of Microsoft Office products installed on a user machine.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* that there is no simple unencrypted equivalent of this for later versions of SQL Server.

However, there are various third party tools which claim to be able to retrieve this, such as:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html
http://www.product-key.com/keyfinders/sql-server-cd-key.htm